# Calling Focus on textbox in window 'x' causes the window 'x ' to be top most

Tags: wpf, window, focus, topmost

I have an application that takes user input, validates it, and either shows an error screen or continues to the next page.

When an error is thrown it calls a static method and passes a resource key for the error message. This static method launches a new window which is top most.

The issue is that this error window runs in it's own thread. In the main window where the user had input, I call focus on a `textbox`. This is so when the user starts typing again, it actually types in the text box. When I call focus on the text box though, it also places the error window behind the Main window.

How can I `Focus` on the textbox without stealing `topmost` from the error window?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the normal focus behaviour. If you were to manually click in the `TextBox` to focus it, that window would become the focused window. There are a few things that you could try to get around this.

Have you tried setting `ErrorWindow.TopMost = true` and `MainWindow.TopMost = false`?

You could try displaying the errors in the first window instead... the users would probably prefer this too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, the error window is topmost. The error window overlays the entire screen. The reason this error window is not displayed in the same window is because there is no reference to the window where the error window is being instantiated. This is due to the the way we have structured the code to separate UI from back end using MVVM. 

I am more interested to see if someone has a way to put the cursor in a textbox without stealing topmost then changing the structure of my code. I have coded a solution, but it is not a good solution and I want it to be better.